# Interactive graphs in android

Tags: android, graph

I am doing an android application where i need to implement interactive graphs.Can any one suggest good libraries to use.
I have gone through achartengine.
I need some interactive charts libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Following two links will help you out :

http://android-graphview.org/

http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-create-a-line-chart

If you want to create custom graph like change the background color then you have create it on canvas

Comment: Your second link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries.
The simplest one is this
[HoloGraphLibrary](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary)

Also 
http://androidplot.com/

https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/

http://android-graphview.org/